# Swig error: member function already defined or declared

Tags: c++, swig, swig-template

I'm pretty much a swig novice so I hope that the problem I'm running into is a basic one. My problem is that I can't seem to get swig to compile an unordered_map. Here's a MWE. Note that I eventually want to use the unordered map as a python dictionary.

```
// UsingUnorderedMap.h
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class UsingUnorderedMap{
public:
    UsingUnorderedMap() = default;
    const std::unordered_map<std::string, double> &getStringDoubleMap() const;
    void setStringDoubleMap(const std::unordered_map<std::string, double> &stringDoubleMap);
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, double> StringDoubleMap;
};
```

```
// UsingUnorderedMap.cpp
#include "UsingUnorderedMap.h"

const std::unordered_map<std::string, double> &UsingUnorderedMap::getStringDoubleMap() const {
    return StringDoubleMap;
}

void UsingUnorderedMap::setStringDoubleMap(const std::unordered_map<std::string, double> &stringDoubleMap) {
    StringDoubleMap = stringDoubleMap;
}
```

```
// UsingUnorderedMap.i
%module UsingUnorderedMap

%{
#include "UsingUnorderedMap.h"
%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_pair.i"
%include "std_unordered_map.i"

namespace std {
    %template(StringDoubleDict) unordered_map<string, double>;
}

%include "UsingUnorderedMap.h"
```

And you can build it with CMake using :

```
# CMakeLists.txt
include(UseSWIG)

set_property(SOURCE UsingUnorderedMap.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(UsingUnorderedMap
        LANGUAGE python
        TYPE MODULE
        SOURCES UsingUnorderedMap.i UsingUnorderedMap.h UsingUnorderedMap.cpp)

set_target_properties(UsingUnorderedMap
        PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

target_include_directories(UsingUnorderedMap PUBLIC
        ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
target_link_libraries(UsingUnorderedMap PUBLIC ${Python_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS UsingUnorderedMap DESTINATION UsingUnorderedMap)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/UsingUnorderedMap.py DESTINATION UsingUnorderedMap)
```

The error I get is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\unordered_map(133): error C2535: 'std::unordered_map<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>>::unordered_map(unsigned __int64,const std::less<std::string> &,const std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>> &)': member function already defined or declared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\unordered_map(128): note: see declaration of 'std::unordered_map<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>>::unordered_map'
D:\LearnSwig\cmake-build-release-visual-studio\src\UsingUnorderedMap\CMakeFiles\UsingUnorderedMap.dir\UsingUnorderedMapPYTHON_wrap.cxx(5059): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unordered_map<std::string,double,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,double>>>' being compiled
...
```

Any help or advice you have would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Must be something with CMake.  I built and used your code directly(with #include <string> and #include <unordered_map> added to the header and without CMake) and it worked with no issues.  I'm not very familar with Cmake.

Comment: Hmm what version of swig did you use?

Comment: The latest: 4.0.2 I can post the non-cmake solution if you want

Comment: Thanks but no its okay - I've also been able to build this with swig 4.0.2 now (CMake was fine). The issue is that the project I'm working on is still using swig 3.0.0 so clearly  theres a problem with handling the `std_unordered_map.i`. Best solution I can think of is to update swig - wish me luck =]

Comment: Just did a huge conversion from Swig 3.00 to Swig 4.01. I used `__swig_getmethods__1 and `__swig_setmethods__` which are no longer supported. For this, you need to use `%attribute` or to make things backwards compatible, you can use extend the classes using `property(GetFunction, SetFunction)`

Comment: I went with `property(getter, setter)` in the end, but `%attribute` is certainly worth checking out. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: In fact, do you know whether`%attribute` adds to the instance dict instead of the class dict? The issue (for my project at least) with making things a property is that this happens at the class level (i.e. `__class__.__dict__`). I currently have things which are instance specific being made properties, so in theory it'd be possible for a second instance to access properties from a first.

Comment: You can see it from each instance. I use a mixture of both since `property` is more flexible for functions with non-standard signatures